# Minify all JavaScript Files in the Sencha App

Tags: sencha-touch, minify

I have a Sencha Application which contains Models, Controllers, Views etc. I need to minify all models, views, controllers, app Javascript file into a single JavaScript file. Any recommendation of tools on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Cmd has an inbuilt function for this. Open up your command prompt, change into the root directory of your project and run:

```
sencha app build production
```

And it will generate a minified version of your app in YourApp/build/production/YourApp.

Comment: When I run this command from the root folder I get the following: Command must be run from an application folder

Comment: When I say root folder I mean the one that contains the app.js file for your application, is this where you are running it from?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is indeed `sencha app build production`

**For a step by step here is an excellent blog post from Sencha**

http://www.sencha.com/blog/getting-started-with-sencha-touch-2-build-a-weather-utility-app-part-1/

Its a three part blog post, you'll have fun following it, and in the third part it does make a build for production.

Here is a demo of how fast loads when is production build.

http://prosp-anonym111.rhcloud.com/simulador/build/production/reestructura/index.html

best regards